# Java - Write Video and Audio at the same time to FFmpeg

Tags: java, process, ffmpeg

Hello fellow developers,

I'm currently developing a tool which can render videos by executing FFmpeg using a Java Process and feeding video frames to it.

I currently use the following FFmpeg command:
`ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -s %WIDTH%x%HEIGHT% -r %FPS% -i - -an -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p "%FILENAME%.mp4"`,
where the placeholders are obviously replaced with real values.

The code I'm using to initialize FFmpeg:

```
    //commandArgs is a list of command line arguments for FFmpeg

    List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
    command.add("ffmpeg");
    command.addAll(commandArgs);

    process = new ProcessBuilder(command).directory(outputFolder).start();
    OutputStream exportLogOut = new FileOutputStream("export.log");
    new StreamPipe(process.getInputStream(), exportLogOut).start();
    new StreamPipe(process.getErrorStream(), exportLogOut).start();
    outputStream = process.getOutputStream();
    channel = Channels.newChannel(outputStream);
```

Then, I have the following method to write a ByteBuffer containing a Video Frame to FFmpeg:

```
public void consume(ByteBuffer buf) {
    try {
        channel.write(buf);
        ByteBufferPool.release(buf);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now, my question is, how would I go ahead and write synchronous Audio Data to the output file? I assume that I need to use multiple pipes, and of course I will have to modify my command line arguments, but I need help:

```
1) what kind of Audio Data do I need to feed FFmpeg with?
2) how do I feed Audio and Video in one go?
3) how do I keep Audio and Video synchronized?
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Greetings,
CrushedPixel

Answer (score 3):

This is what muxing formats are for, ideally you want to use a muxing format to feed data to FFmpeg. An example of how FFmpeg does this internally is the interaction between ffmpeg.exe and ffserver.exe, and it does so through a custom/internal streaming file format called [FFM](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffserver.html#FFM_002c-FFM2-formats). Complete details about the implementation can be found [here](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/ffmenc_8c-source.html). You can obviously also use other muxing formats, as simple as AVI. Synchronization is automatic since the file provides timestamps.

As for the type of audio data, this can really be anything, most people will use raw, interleaved PCM audio (either float or int16).

Comment: You might be able to input from two "named pipes" inputs or the like, as long as you're guaranteed to have synchronous input [?]

Comment: @rogerdpack is it possible to safely obtain named pipes on *any* OS?

Comment: @rogerdpack I was hestitating to suggest named pipes because of the sync issue, but yes, if you can externally keep the video framerate and audio samplerate constant and continuous, that's easier.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://github.com/artclarke/humble-video which is a wrapper around ffmpeg in java. You can add video/audio streams dinamically to an encoder.

Comment: This is not an option as we cannot distribute our work under the AGPL License.

Comment: I might be wrong, but the license AGPL is for modifications, and distribution of the humble-video, not the software that is using humble-video as a library/API. Also there is an older, deprecated version of the software at https://github.com/artclarke/xuggle-xuggler which is GPL, if that suits your requirements.

Comment: You are wrong - we have to distribute our tool as AGPL/GPL as well, which is not possible for our project. Thanks anyway :)